# Assign Node To Other Menus Besides Main Menu

Tags: routes

Is there a module or technique which will allow us to assign a node to a menu -besides- the Main Menu. Users find it annoying that the only menu they can assign a new page to has to be based on the Main Menu. We have many custom menu blocks and it would be nice if the user could set up the page menu in one step rather than having to save the page, then go to the Admin/Structure/Menus and assign the page to the link.

BTW: We're using Kickstart 2 Omega theme if that makes any difference.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restricting the menus to which a Content Type can be added is configured on the Content Type itself (Structure -> Content Types -> Edit or `admin/structure/types/manage/[content-type]`) within the "Menu settings" tab:

[image: Available Menus]

By default, only the Main menu is selected. Simply check off additional menus to make them available on the node add/edit page for that Content Type.

Comment: D'OH! Must've been having senior moment. CHEERS!